# Extract and display only year from each lines on Notepad++ using regex

Tags: notepad++, regex

I have strings like that

```
hack SIGN (2005) g$
5 Cm Per Second - Makoto Shinkai Collection (2007)
Abenobashi (2002) gd
Ai City - La Notte Dei Cloni (1986) dfg
AIKA (1997)
Anna Dai Capelli Rossi (1979) £$"£
```

I want display on Notepad++

```
2005
2007
2002
1986
1997
1979
```

I use this regex but seems not works well

FIND:

```
\(\b(19|20)\d{2}\b\)
```

REPLACE

```
r\n\1\1
```

But it return me text like this

```
hack SIGN r
2020 g$
5 Cm Per Second - Makoto Shinkai Collection r
2020
Abenobashi r
2020 gd
Ai City - La Notte Dei Cloni r
1919 dfg
..
```

So this regex don't work like expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the instructions below upon pressing <kbd>`Ctrl`</kbd>+<kbd>`H`</kbd> from [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) to match a group of 4 digit numbers per each line and print just those characters giving you the expected results.

1. **Find what:** `^.*?(\d{4}+).*$`

   > [image]
2. **Replace with:**  `$1`
3. **Search Mode:** `Regular expression`
4. Press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

---

**Results**

```
2005
2007
2002
1986
1997
1979
```

[image]

---

### Further Resources

> [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
>
> **Anchors**
>
> Anchors match a position in the line, rather than a particular
>   character.
>
> `^`
>
> This matches the start of a line (except when used inside a set, see
>   above).
>
> `$`
>
> This matches the end of a line.
>
> **Ranges or kinds of characters**
>
> `[^...]`
>
> The complement of the characters in the set.
>
> **Single-character matches**
>
> `., \c`
>
> Matches any character. If you check the box which says ". matches
>   newline", the dot will indeed do that, enabling the "any" character to
>   run over multiple lines. With the option unchecked, then . will only
>   match characters within a line, and not the line ending characters (\r
>   and \n)
>
> **Multiplying operators**
>
> `*`
>
> This matches 0 or more instances of the previous character, as many as
>   it can. For example, Sa*m matches Sm, Sam, Saam, and so on.
>
> `*?`
>
> Zero or more of the previous group, but minimally: the shortest
>   matching string, rather than the longest string as with the "greedy" *
>   operator. Thus, m.*?o applied to the text margin-bottom: 0; will match
>   margin-bo, whereas m.*o will match margin-botto.
>
> `{n}`
>
> Matches n copies of the element it applies to.
>
> `+`
>
> This matches 1 or more instances of the previous character, as many as
>   it can.
>
> **Groups**
>
> `(...)`
>
> Parentheses mark a subset of the regular expression. The string
>   matched by the contents of the parentheses `( )` can be re-used as a
>   backreference or as part of a replace operation; see Substitutions,
>   below.
>
> Groups may be nested.
>
> `(?<some name>...), (?'some name'...),(?(some name)...)`
>
> **Ranges or kinds of characters**
>
> `\d`
>
> A digit in the 0-9 range, same as **[[:digit:]]**.
>
> ---
>
> **Substitutions**
>
> `$n, ${n}, \n`
>
> Returns what matched the subexpression numbered n. Negative indices
>   are not alowed.

Comment: It doesn't work if there something like `123456` in a line.

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with this question though but I clarified for the OP....There are no 6 consecutive digits in the data examples provided so I didn't code for variables outside of the scope of the question as worded.  This solution is not dependent on the `YYYY` digits being enclosed by `()` parenthesis characters so it'll return `YYYY` whether enclosed or not. Furthermore, if there is only `YYYY` on a line alone then this solution will not delete it unlike the other solution provided that does. Last but not least, I answered with a working answer first before you.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^(?:.*?\(((?:19|20)\d{2})\).*|.*\R)$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- *DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^                   : beginning of line
  (?:               : start non capture group
    .*?             : 0 or more any character but newline, not greedy
    \(              : open parenthesis
      (             : start group 1
        (?:19|20)   : non capture group, 19 or 20
        \d{2}       : 2 digits
      )             : end group 1
    \)              : close parenthesis
    .*              : 0 or more any character but newline
   |                : OR
    .*              : 0 or more any character but newline
    \R?             : any kind of linebreak, optional
  )                 : end non capture group
$                   : end of line
```

**Given an input like:**

```
hack SIGN (2005) g$
5 Cm Per Second - Makoto Shinkai Collection (2007)
Abenobashi (2002) gd
Ai City - La Notte Dei Cloni (1986) dfg
AIKA (1997)
Anna Dai Capelli Rossi (1979) £$"£
123456 1234
(123) 4567
```

**We got:**

```
2005
2007
2002
1986
1997
1979
```

Comment: I do not know which of the 2 answers to choose ... because work both..

Comment: @SuperSonic: The other answer doesn't delete line like `123456 789`, see the last two lines of my example.